# Php/Laravel | Issue with array

Tags: php, laravel

When i `dd($MyArray);`

I have a response like in the image 
[image]

I'm asking why this code not working ?

```
$Id = $MyArray->id;
```

Error : Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: Because the syntaxis to get an  Array element by index is $MyArray['id']. This other syntaxis $MyArray->id; is to get Object attributte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it's not an object, so you should use the square bracket syntax `$MyArray['id']` or cast it to an object `((object)$MyArray)->id`

Answer (score 1):

It is associative array. You access properties like: $MyArray['id']

Answer (score 0):

You can't access array element by `->`

```
 $MyArray['id'];
```

Or just convert array to object by

```
 $newObject = (object)$MyArray;
 $newObject->id;
```